# WordPress link to another page in site does not render a <body>

Tags: theme-development

I have a link from my main WordPress home page to another page there, they both have different header/footer and css/js files.
When I press the link, it does send me to /art yet it displays only the `<head>` and doesn't send the `<body>`. Only after refreshing the page it does.

Code follows:

### header.php

`<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'Art' ) ) ; ?>"><div id="art-link"></div></a>`

### page.php

```
if (get_the_title() == 'Art') {
    get_header('Art');

} else {
    get_header();
}
if (get_the_title() == 'Art'){
    require('art-page.php');

}
require('workshop-page.php');

if (get_the_title() == 'Art') {
    get_footer('Art');
} else {
    get_footer();
}
```

### page-art.php

```
get_header('art');
echo 'art test';
get_footer('art');
```

Any idea what may be causing this issue?

Comment: Are you sure the `header-art.php` and `footer-art.php` both exist in your theme's folder, and they both have the proper `<body>` tags inside?

Comment: You've got `require( 'art-page.php' )` in the `page.php` code, but then you reversed the name (`page-art.php`) for the template file name.